# Reproduce ios7 buttons color effect when pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ios7

This is a duplicate question with : [How to animate transition from one state to another for UIControl/UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237956/how-to-animate-transition-from-one-state-to-another-for-uicontrol-uibutton) but not with : [Fading out an UIButton when touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517149/fading-out-an-uibutton-when-touched) as mentioned.

However the answer provided by Marty in : [How to animate transition from one state to another for UIControl/UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237956/how-to-animate-transition-from-one-state-to-another-for-uicontrol-uibutton) seems to be good but don't work for me, there is no animation between the highlight state and the normal state.

What I want to do, is to replicate the cool effect on the rounded buttons in ios7 : when pressed the button is filled with color which quickly disappear with a fade out effect.

I have 2 images for normal state and highlight state, and basically I think I should subclass the button and insert the animation effect between them

Any idea on what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Don't simply ask your exact same question again because the other one didn't get answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer found here [Fading out an UIButton when touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517149/fading-out-an-uibutton-when-touched) I modified the code as shown below, where overlayButton is an hidden UIImage situated over the button

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender {
overlayButton.alpha = 1;
[overlayButton setHidden:FALSE];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endIgnoringInteractionEvents)];
overlayButton.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```